# Run RESTful Client Server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, web-services, rest

I am following the tutorial from this link to learn about RESTful programming.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html

I have done the project under '7. CRUD RESTful webservice'.

When I run the Client (heading 7.5) for this project (Run as Application), I should get a form to input the details to be POSTed to the REST web service. But the form is shown in the Console window which shows the raw HTML file rather than the html page as rendered by a browser.

Any suggestions on what I am doing wrongly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Section 7.5 of that tutorial is just a simple, hard-coded demonstration of interacting with the web service; it is not an app that accepts input and it certainly is not a browser. A (static) HTML page that accepts input and posts to the web service would not be hard to assemble, but it's outside the scope of that tutorial.

If you just need a client to test your REST service, there are lots of choices. For example:

- [an Eclipse plugin that is a REST client](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/rest-client#.Ut2iG2Qo5NQ)
- [Postman, a Chrome browser app that does the same thing](http://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: Can you suggest me any tutorials/links that allow me to POST data to a REST web service using HTML form? Thanks.

Comment: I edited my answer with some REST client tools that you might consider.